# How to access nested array values

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, nest

I have the following array that I need to use in a laravel email view template

```
$inputs['test']
```

Which looks like this when I `dd($inputs['test']);`

```
Array:1[
    "order" => array:2[
        0 => 523
        1 => 522
     ]
 ]
```

I've tried this in my foreach loop but it doesn't work

```
foreach($inputs['test']->order as $test){
        echo $test;}
```

What syntax would I need to echo each value from the order nested array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use array not object loop:

```
foreach($inputs['test']['order'] as $test){           
        echo $test;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You use square braces [] to access array values, arrows -> to access properties on objects

```
foreach($inputs['test']['order'] as $test){
        echo $test;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the helper method for `Arr` `facade` and avoid all these complications.

For instance, if you've something like

```
$array = ['products' => ['desk' => ['price' => 100]]];
```

You can do this

```
return Arr::get($array, 'products.desk.price');
```

and it will return `100`. The best part is if the key price doesn't exist, it doesn't throw and error.

So, if the array had to be like this

```
$array = ['products' => ['desk' => []];
```

and you did this

```
return Arr::get($array, 'products.desk.price');
```

It would return null and not any error even though the item doesn't exist.
You can also set a default value if you want like this

```
return Arr::get($array, 'products.desk.price', 2);
```

This would return 2 if the price doesn't exist.
[https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-get](http://Arr%20helper%20laravel)

Comment: Thanks for being the only Laravel-like answer, this is exactly the kind of headache Laravel is meant to solve.

Comment: Check out their helpers section in the doc. It will blow your mind the kind of hazards that it solves. I've worked with django, fastapi but nothing matches the convenience of laravel. @HashimAziz

Answer (score 2):

Try

`$inputs['test']['order'][0]`

Basically, php reads the nested arrays as arrays in arrays .. so no matter how many arrays nested you can always use `[][][][][]`

[php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

### Example #6 Accessing array elements

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    42    => 24,
    "multi" => array(
         "dimensional" => array(
             "array" => "foo"
         )
    )
);

var_dump($array["foo"]);
var_dump($array[42]);
var_dump($array["multi"]["dimensional"]["array"]);
?>
```

and you can use it in looping as such

```
foreach($inputs['test']['order'] as $test){
    echo $test;}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have what is key and what is value of arrays
They are multiple ways to echo arrays this is one way

```
foreach($inputs['test']['order'] as $key =>  $test){
        echo 'Key ->'.$key.'<br/>';    
        echo 'Value ->'. $test. '<br/>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$myEcho = function($x){
    if(is_array($x)){foreach($x as $one){$myEcho($one);}
    }else{ echo $x; }
  };
array_map($myEcho, $inputs['test']['order']);
```

Answer (score 0):

data_get($mainArrayName, '*.nestedArrayName.*.NestedArrayKeyName');

try it..hope this work
No need a foreach here

Comment: `data_get()` is not an existing core PHP function.